# Label not being updated

Tags: swift, macos, label

I am trying to update a label to indicate status, but it is not being refreshed/shown as expected

```
func setStatusText(status: String) {
    statusText.stringValue = status;
}

func doSomething() {
    setStatusText(status: "Activating license"); // This is never shown
    var rc = PerformAction()

    if (rc == 0) {
        setStatusText(status: "\(action) succeeded") // Correctly displayed
    } else {
        setStatusText(status: "\(action) failed") // Correctly displayed
    }
```

The status update before the action is never being shown, but the status set right after the action is correctly displayed. What do I do to be sure the first status is shown?

Edited: I tried something else to try to isolate it. I added a button press, which will set text, sleep, and then set text again. I never see "first" in the status.

```
@IBAction func TestSettingText(_ sender: Any) {
    self.statusText.stringValue = "first";
    sleep(15)
    self.statusText.stringValue = "second";
}
```

Comment: What type of variable is statusText?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger, and putting a breakpoint on the `var rc =` line and the following line. Make sure that the label updates before continuing to the following line

Comment: Yes, tried in the debugger and the status isn't updated until after that line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Trying to update NSTextField in a loop, but it only gets the last value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230517/swift-trying-to-update-nstextfield-in-a-loop-but-it-only-gets-the-last-value)

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate of that, although there may be some similarities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly `PerformAction` does but it seems like it finishes quickly so you just can't see the `Activating license` status. It is there but only for a very brief moment and instantly changed to the next status

Comment: There are some cases where it takes a bit of time and even in those cases I am never seeing the first label update, or if I step through debugger.

Comment: what if you remove everything after PerformAction?

Comment: In that case it does show the first/original label status. So it appears that they are both set at the same time, so the second overwrites the first...but again it is only happening after the action is done

Comment: what if you remove PerformAction() call? I'm pretty sure the status will be there